# getting model's all valid fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

This question is about ruby on rails.  What is the way to get the list of all keys that I can pass to a ruby on rails model's constructor? `post.attributes` method gives me the list of all actual columns in that table.  But it doesn't include fields generated by associations.  It would not include `:blog`.  How can I attributes plus fields created by association?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check the attributes of `Model`:

1. `Model` => return Model fields with their datatype
2. `Model.new` => return Model fields with their default values
3. `Model.inspect` => return `string` of Model fields with their datatype
4. `Model.attribute_names` => returns array of attributes
5. `Model.column_names` => returns array of attributes
6. `Model.new.attributes` => return hash of all fields with default values